# Java Jackson generating Json but not XML

Tags: java, jackson

I'm developing a program in Java and I'm using Jackson the output XML and JSON.
at the moment I'm getting an error when I output in XML but not in JSON.

The error is the following [error message](http://pastebin.com/hUmrTb4X)

The classes that I'm trying to output are [This one](http://pastebin.com/Aq1idqk6) with an instance of [this one](http://pastebin.com/tQ2R6S4i) inside as data. I have [this output](http://pastebin.com/fkh504Qi) when I request JSON....

```
Error Message
    Jan 27, 2013 12:02:55 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:157)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao.Users nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:637)
    ... 37 more
```

message wrapper

```
package pt.eoliveira.appmanager.wrappers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "message")
public class Message {

    private int error = 0;
    private String errorMessage = "";
    private Object data;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(int error, String errorMessage) {
        this.error = error;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public Message(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Message setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    public Message setError(int error, String errorMessage) {
        this.error = error;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        return this;
    }

    public int getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public String getErroMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

class that goes inside the data object

```
package pt.eoliveira.appmanager.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import pt.eoliveira.appmanager.utils.MySqlTools;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userId = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPermissions", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.permissions = :permissions")
})

public class Users implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "password")
    @XmlTransient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "permissions")
    private int permissions;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Sessions sessions;

    @JoinColumn(name = "country", referencedColumnName = "country_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Country country;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private Collection<Apps> appsCollection;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Users(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Users(Integer userId, String username, String password, String email, int permissions) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(int permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Sessions getSessions() {
        return sessions;
    }

    public void setSessions(Sessions sessions) {
        this.sessions = sessions;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Apps> getAppsCollection() {
        return appsCollection;
    }

    public void setAppsCollection(Collection<Apps> appsCollection) {
        this.appsCollection = appsCollection;
    }

    public boolean isValid(String password) {
        try {
            return this.password.equals(MySqlTools.MD5Encode(password));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
            return false;
        }
        Users other = (Users) object;
        if ((this.userId == null && other.userId != null) || (this.userId != null && !this.userId.equals(other.userId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users{" + "userId=" + userId + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", email=" + email + ", permissions=" + permissions + ", sessions=" + sessions + ", country=" + country + ", appsCollection=" + appsCollection + '}';
    }
}
```

Example Json Output

```
    {"error":0,"data":
    {"userId":17,"username":"xxxx","password":"xxxx","email":"xxxx","permissions":1,"sessions":
    {"sessionId":8,"sessionKey":"b0880029fae3b4588c37640f8452b2da","creationStamp":2017052136},"country":{"countryId":177,"iso2":"PT","shortName":"Portugal","longName":"Portuguese Republic","iso3":"PRT","numcode":"620","unMember":"yes","callingCode":"351","cctld":".pt"}},
    "erroMessage":""}
```

The method where I generate the output is

```
@GET
@Path("validate")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Message validate(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Users rtn = validateUser(username, password);
        if (rtn != null) {
                if (rtn.getSessions() == null) {
                        rtn.setSessions(new Sessions(MySqlTools.MD5Encode(System.currentTimeMillis() + MySqlTools.SALT), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), rtn));
                        super.edit(rtn);
                }
                return new Message(rtn);
        }
        return new Message(1,"Invalid Username or Password");
}
```

For me, the odd part is why does it only give the error when is try to get the output as XML?...

Comment: You should not link to your code and stacktraces. Post the relevant parts here.

Comment: I tried but since it was so much text i feared that wouldn't good enough formated

Comment: Your stack trace indicates your data is being serialized with the default Sun JAXB provider. 1) Include your marshaling code in your question. 2) Include the other code you linked, directly to the question.

Comment: i'm sorry what do you mean by marshaling code? any ideas on what is causing the error? Thank you

Comment: Seems like you may not have registered Jackson XML provider -- by default Jersey uses JAXB based one, not Jackson one. One you need can be found at: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider